# Преобразование русского текста в Hex и обратно

Tags: delphi, строки

Есть две рабочие функции, но при декодировании из Hex - не воспринимается русский текст ?

Текст до обработки:

```
Тест test
Тест test
Тест test
```

Кодирование в Hex:

```
D2E5F1F22074657374
D2E5F1F22074657374
D2E5F1F22074657374
```

Декодирование из Hex в текст (То есть - не воспринимает русские буквы):

```
Oano test
Oano test
Oano test
```

Код функций - Кодирования/декодирования:

```
function String2Hex(const Buffer: Ansistring): string;
begin
  SetLength(result, 2 * Length(Buffer));
  BinToHex(@Buffer[1], PWideChar(@result[1]), Length(Buffer));
end;

function HexToStr(H: String): String;
var
  I, b: Integer;
begin
  result := '';
  for I := 1 to Length(H) div 2 do
  begin
    b := StrToInt('$' + Copy(H, (I - 1) * 2 + 1, 2));
    if b < 10 then
      b := b + ord('0');
    result := result + Char(b);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А чем не устроила `HexToBin`?

```
function HexToStr(const H: string): AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(H) div 2 div SizeOf(Result[1]));
  HexToBin(PChar(H), Result[1], Length(H) div SizeOf(H[1]));
end;
```

Comment: Дело в том что: при её использовании, весь текст, после декодирования - в виде знаков вопроса ???????.

Comment: Не заметил, что вы с какого-то перепугу кодируете `AnsiString`. Исправил ответ